# Name of this geometric point?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology

Draw a triangle. At one of the vertices, draw a line through it that bisects the angle. At each of the other two vertices, draw a line through it which is perpendicular to the line that bisects its angle. The three lines meet at a point. What is the proper, formal name of this point?

Comment: excenter or excentre, depending on your preferred spelling of "center/centre". 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle

Comment: I'm so sorry I wouldn't have asked such a ditzy question had I known that the great Noam Elkies of all mathematicians would've answered. Thank you so much!